# Magento 2.2.2 Admin Form Multiselect Box Issue

Tags: forms, uicomponent, fieldsets, multiselect

My Admin Ui Component Form was working fine , but all of a sudden , the `Multiselect` box `went out of proportion` from the rest of the field . Does anybody faced the same issue or anyone know how to fix it!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your label in multislelect add **Sort By**

```
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label Name</item>
```

To

```
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label Name Sort By</item>
```